# Django how to add a model instance with a foreign key field if the referenced model instance does not exist

Tags: python, sql, django, orm, legacy-database

I am working with a legacy database within an AS400 system connected to my Django project. I am trying to configure my models in the best way possible and set up relationships correctly but I am running into an issue related to adding an instance of a model that has a foreign key field to another model but the instance of that model might not exist yet.

Here is an example, consider the following two models:

```
class CLIENTPF(models.Model):
    id = models.BigAutoField(db_column='CLNTID', primary_key=True)
    fname = models.CharField(db_column='CLNTFNAME', max_length=30, unique=True, null=True)
    lname = models.CharField(db_column='CLNTLNAME', max_length=30)
    dob = models.CharField(db_column='CLNTDOB', max_length=10)

    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = '"XPFLORIS"."CLIENTPF"'

class MOVIEPF(models.Model):
    movie_name = models.CharField(db_column='MOVNAME', max_length=30, primary_key=True)
    star_fname = models.ForeignKey(CLIENTPF, to_field='fname', on_delete=models.PROTECT, db_column='STARACTF', max_length=30)
    star_lname = models.CharField(db_column='STARACTL', max_length=30)
    genere = models.CharField(db_column='GENERE', max_length=30)
    release_date = models.CharField(db_column='RELDATE', max_length=10)

    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = '"XPFLORIS"."MOVIEPF"'
```

The "star_fname" field in MOVIEPF is a Foreign key to the "fname" field in CLIENTPF. So if I wanted to add an instance to the MOVIEPF table in my views.py with the following ORM I would get an error since "Rowan" is just a string and not an instance of the CLIENTPF model.

```
 new_movie = MOVIEPF(movie_name="Johnny English", star_fname="Rowan", star_lname="Atkinson", genere="Comedy", release_date="02/12/2003")
    new_movie.save()
```

Instead this code would work:

```
new_movie = MOVIEPF(movie_name="Johnny English", star_fname=CLIENTPF.objects.get(id=0), star_lname="Atkinson", genere="Comedy", release_date="02/12/2003")
new_movie.save()
```

My problem however is that I want to add an instance to MOVIEPF with the "star_fname" field value to be "Rowan" even without there existing a CLIENTPF instance with this "fname" but it should recognize it once an instance is added to CLIENTPF with the corresponding name in the "fname" field.

Does anyone know if this is possible? There is a workaround but it requires not using these relational field attributes in my models like ForeignKey which I would like to take advantage of if possible since this would make my ORM queries a lot more efficient.

Comment: I have a vague feeling you could maybe make it somewhat work by making that field read-only?  You'd then have to write to the CLIENTPF table directly, though.

Comment: Did you tried this: `star_fname__fname="Rowan"`

Comment: @Ahtisham Unfortunately the results in the following error:
MOVIEPF() got an unexpected keyword argument 'star_fname__fname'

Comment: No you need to create a dictionary of fields like this `kwargs = {'star_fname__fname': 'Rowan'}` similarly add other fields in it and then call a create method like `MOVIEPF.objects.create(**kwargs)`

Comment: Even with adding the other fields, I am getting the same error as above for using the keyword argument `star_fname__fname` within the dictionary. If I change this to just `star_fname` the error goes back to complaining about the field type:
`Cannot assign "'Rowan'": "MOVIEPF.star_fname" must be a "CLIENTPF" instance.`

Comment: try with `star_fname_id=1` that will work. Just add the id of `CLIENTPF`

Comment: `new_movie = MOVIEPF(movie_name="Johnny English", star_fname_id=1, star_lname="Atkinson", genere="Comedy", release_date="02/12/2003")
    new_movie.save()` 
This does in fact create the model instance yes... but there is no value for the foreign key field `star_fname` which makes me unable to reference other models using this foreign key relationship if a CLIENTPF model with the matching `fname` field gets created after this MOVIEPF model.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> but the instance of that model might not exist yet.

If you are unsure about the existence of `CLIENTPF` instance and it is blocking you from creating `MOVIEPF` instance then you can either set `null=True` to `star_fname` field to allow null values or you need to create a an instance of `CLIENTPF` before populating the `MOVIEPF`:

```
client = CLIENTPF.objects.filter(fname="Rowan").first()
if client is None:
    client = CLIENTPF.objects.create(fname="Rowan", lname="David", dob="02/12/2003") 
    
new_movie = MOVIEPF(movie_name="Johnny English", star_fname=client, star_lname="Atkinson", genere="Comedy", release_date="02/12/2003")
new_movie.save()
```

I don't think there is any other way to create related model except above.

Edit:

You can also try [get_or_create](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/models/querysets/#get-or-create) to get the instance if existing or create it.

Comment: This solution would technically work... but I wish the Django relationships were a bit more flexible and you could have these "temporary" values in place of model references.  Do you know if this is a request to implement in future versions of Django? Thank you for your help